# Getting text boxes on the same line

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Right now the two text boxes and the '=' sign are on two different line.

like this:

[image]

I like to get them all on the same line , like this:

[image]

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple horizontal stack panel will work, but you may like the auto-sizing capabilities of the grid.

```
<Grid Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock>CONVERTER</TextBlock>
        <RadioButton>Area</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>Currency</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>Temperature</RadioButton>

        <!--
            For specific-sized widths, a simple horizontal stack panel will do,
            along with margins to make sure there is padding around the equal sign.
        -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Width="150"/>
            <TextBlock Text="=" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBox Width="150"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--
            For edit controls that scale based on the screen width,
            you can use a grid. 
        -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0"
                       FontSize="24" Text="="/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition.width.aspx for details on how to define the grid columns.

Answer (score 3):

1. put them inside a `StackPanel`
2. set StackPanel's Orientation=Horizontal

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. You can use stackpanel or wrappanel and use orientation = horizontal. Or you can use the grid and use two columns and put the textboxes in those.

Comment: There is no built-in wrappanel in Win Phone.